# Expresso Store Order confirmation page

Tags: expresso-store

I'm having a slight issue with expresso store, was wondering if anyone can help me out.  The problem is on the last step, when they enter the credit card details.  I've set the following

return="shop/thank_you/ORDER_HASH"

and

secure="yes"

The final page with the order confirmation doesn't display properly as there's extra text in the url.

I should be getting mydomain.com/en/shop/thank_you/ORDER_HASH but I'm actually getting

mydomian.com/en/https:/mydomain.comm:443/https:/mydomain.com/shop/thank_you/ORDER_HASH

Just to note, the order does complete successfully, it just doesn't display the final page due to the extra details in the URL.

Final Confirmation page code:

```
 <header class="purchase-steps">
  <h6>Step to Purchase</h6>
  <nav> <a href="#" class="">1</a> <a href="#" class="">2</a> <a href="#" class="">3</a> <a href="#" class="">4</a> <a href="#" class="">5</a> <a href="#" class="active last">6</a> </nav>
</header>
      <header class="pageTitle">
  <h3> Thank you for your order! </h3>
</header>
{exp:store:orders order_hash="{segment_3}"}
<h4>Your order ID is: <span class="blue">{order_id}</span></h4>
{/exp:store:orders}
<p>It is currently being processed by our sales team. You will receive an email confirming your details. Please contact us at (01) 123 4567 if you have any queries about this purchase.</p>
<br>
<a href="#" class="more button green">Return to Our Products</a> <br>
<br>
```

ht access file:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php

RewriteEngine on

# remove index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]  

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2013 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

Header unset ETag
FileETag None

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #------------------- remove trailing slash -------------------
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

    #------------------- CE Cache Static Driver -------------------
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !ACT|URL [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/ce_cache/0158f6/static%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html -f [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /_static_cache_handler.php%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you remove secure="yes" does the page redirect as suspected? Also can you post your final checkout page template code and your htaccess file

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your help.  I've edited the original comment to include the code and ht access.  If  I remove the secure="yes" and manually change the address to https, the page redirects correctly.

Comment: Hi again , forgot to mention that it's a multi language site and we're using the Publisher module.  We have had a few errors where Publisher has being causing errors in other parts of Store, so this is a possible explaination.

Comment: I'm really not sure what's happening with this, but I've managed to work around it by using EpicVoyages Force SSL plugin to do the switch.  http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/force-ssl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer provided in comments:

> I'm really not sure what's happening with this, but I've managed to work around it by using EpicVoyages Force SSL plugin to do the switch.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/force-ssl